# Is a function that maps every compact set to a compact set continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A continuous function maps a compact set to a compact set. Is the converse of this true? That is, is a function that maps every compact set to a compact set necessarily continuous?

Comment: Every function with a finite range obviously satisfies the condition, and you should be able to produce examples of this which are not continuous.

Answer (score 22):

No. Consider the discontinuous function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \geq 0\\ -1 & x <0.\end{cases}$$ Then for any subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (not just compact subsets), $f(A)$ is either $\emptyset$, $\{-1\}$, $\{1\}$, or $\{-1, 1\}$, all of which are compact.

Comment: Wow. This even works if you replace "continuous" with "locally continuous everywhere".

Comment: @JanDvorak: What do you mean by 'locally continuous'?

Comment: As in, every point has a continuous neighborhood

Comment: I don't think that's true at $0$.

Comment: My mistake. A function that's locally continuous everywhere is continuous. OTOH there is a difference between locally monotonous everywhere and monotonous globally. There is also monotonous on every defined interval, which is again slightly different.

Answer (score 8):

The characteristic function of the rationals maps every set, in particular every compact set, to a compact set. But it is discontinuous at every point.

Answer (score 5):

The most bare-bones counterexample is probably the identity function from a two element set equipped with the trivial topology to a two element set equipped with a nontrivial topology.